# css align text in table

Tags: css

In the following how to make the text(Pick one or more) appear under the text Options in css

```
<table >
<tr><td>options (Pick one or more)</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Check that http://jsfiddle.net/dprBX/

Comment: @Sleeperson, I dont think he meant two different rows.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `<br/>` ?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Options<br/>
      (Pick one or more)
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

<table>
   <tr><td>options</br>(Pick one or more)</td></tr>
   </table>

?

Answer (score 0):

Place the span for (Pick one or more) text and give style display:block;

see below:

```
<table class="ab">
<tr><td>options <span>(Pick one or more)</span></td></tr>
</table>

table.ab td span{
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it could be hacked, the right answer is that you need more structure, whether it is a br between 'options' & '(pick...)', or you shove the 2nd part into a div.  You could even get by with removing part of the string (say, options) and using css :content modifiers.

However, no real CSS will help you here.  You need to modify structure or use JS.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways...

one is adding a table row:

```
<tr><td>Options</td></tr>
<tr><td>(Pick one or more)</tr></td>
```

2nd is adding a line break

```
<tr><td>Options<br/>(Pick one or more</td></tr>
```

3rd is adding a block element (such as a `<p>`, `<div>` or a `<h1...6>`), as such:

```
<tr>
<td>
<p>Options</p>
(Pick one or more
</td>
</tr>
```

or:

```
<tr>
<td>
Options
<p>(Pick one or more)</p>
</td>
</tr>
```

So it comes down to what your needs are...